# Remove fee from Woocommerce order using hook before inserting to database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Is there any way **to remove a fee from an Woocommerce order** before saving it to the database?

I have tried the following hooks, to no success

1. woocommerce_before_save_order_items
2. woocommerce_calculate_totals
3. wp_insert_post_data

I also tried to edit the fee total as below, but the fee still gets saved to the database

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'cst_my_hook_1', 10, 3);
function cst_my_hook_1() {
    WC()->cart->set_fee_total(0);
}
```

I am sharing a screenshot to make my requirements more clear. Woocommerce cart class (class-wc-cart.php) contains a public function to add fees, so I think there should be ways to remove it too.

I used the hook "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" to add the fee shown in the screenshot. Now I want to remove it before saving to DB.

I am using **Wordpress 5.7.1**, **Woocommerce 5.2.1**

[image]

Comment: Is "Total Tax Payment" a woocommerce fee? How is it added? try to gve us more details and explanations please…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec "Total Tax Payment" is a custom fee I added using the hook "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" ... I called the add_fee function of cart class inside this hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable fees from order once checking out, use this simple following hooked function, that will clean all fees from orders and email notifications:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'order_created_disable_fees' );
function order_created_disable_fees( $order ) {
    $targeted_item_name = __( "Total Tax Payment", "woocommerce" );

    foreach( $order->get_items( 'fee' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
        if( $targeted_item_name === $item['name'] ) {
            $order->remove_item($item_id);
        }       
    }
    $order->calculate_totals();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now if you want to remove the fees, but keep original total order amount, use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'order_created_disable_fees' );
function order_created_disable_fees( $order ) {
    $targeted_item_name = __( "Total Tax Payment", "woocommerce" );

    foreach( $order->get_items( 'fee' ) as $item_id => $item ) {
        if( $targeted_item_name === $item['name'] ) {
            $order->remove_item($item_id);
        }
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thanks brother for the code snippet ... it works fine! I just added an if condition to ensure that only the fee with the name 'Total Tax Payment' get removed

Answer (score 1):

If you want **to remove a fee from an order before saving it in the database** you can use the [**`woocommerce_create_order`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-checkout.html#source-view.321) hook that fires before the order is created within the `create_order` method of the `WC_Checkout` class.

Based on this answer:

- [Remove applied specific fee from Cart programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814014/remove-applied-specific-fee-from-cart-programmatically)

you will be able to remove the fee from the cart.

> However, you will also have to recalculate the **totals** and **taxes** *(it works whether the fee is taxable or not, and even with multiple tax classes)*.

**REMOVE A FEE FROM CART AND RECALCULATE TOTALS**

```
// removes a specific fee by name before creating the order and recalculates the totals
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'remove_specific_fee_from_cart_before_creating_order', 10, 2 );
function remove_specific_fee_from_cart_before_creating_order( $order_id = null, $order ) {

    // get the fees added to the cart
    $fees = WC()->cart->get_fees();

    // initialize taxes (if the fee is not taxable)
    $fee_tax = 0;
    $fee_tax_data = array();

    foreach ( $fees as $key => $fee ) {
        // replace "Total Tax Payment" with the name of the fee you added to the cart
        if ( $fee->name == 'Total Tax Payment' ) {
            // gets the data to recalculate the cart total
            $fee_amount = $fee->amount;
            if ( $fee->taxable ) {
                $fee_tax      = $fee->tax;
                $fee_tax_data = $fee->tax_data;
            }
            // removes the fee
            unset( $fees[$key] );
            break;
        }
    }

    // updates the cart fees
    WC()->cart->fees_api()->set_fees( $fees );

    // gets the current values of the cart to be recalculated
    $cart_total     = WC()->cart->get_total(''); // returns the float value instead of HTML code
    $cart_total_tax = WC()->cart->get_total_tax();
    $cart_fee_taxes = WC()->cart->get_fee_taxes();

    // if the fee is taxable
    // recalculates the taxes by removing the taxes of the removed fee
    if ( ! empty( $fee_tax_data ) ) {
        foreach ( $cart_fee_taxes as $fee_tax_key => $fee_tax ) {
            if ( array_key_exists( $fee_tax_key, $fee_tax_data ) ) {
                $cart_fee_taxes[$fee_tax_key] = $fee_tax - $fee_tax_data[$fee_tax_key];
            }
        }
    }

    // updates the cart totals
    WC()->cart->set_total( $cart_total - $fee_amount - $fee_tax );
    WC()->cart->set_total_tax( $cart_total_tax - $fee_tax );
    WC()->cart->set_fee_taxes( $cart_fee_taxes );

    return $order_id;
}
```

**REMOVES A FEE FROM CART WITHOUT RECALCULATING THE TOTALS**

```
// removes a specific fee by name before creating the order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'remove_specific_fee_from_cart_before_creating_order', 10, 2 );
function remove_specific_fee_from_cart_before_creating_order( $order_id = null, $order ) {

    // get the fees added to the cart
    $fees = WC()->cart->get_fees();

    foreach ( $fees as $key => $fee ) {
        // replace "Total Tax Payment" with the name of the fee you added to the cart
        if ( $fee->name == 'Total Tax Payment' ) {
            // removes the fee
            unset( $fees[$key] );
            break;
        }
    }

    // updates the cart fees
    WC()->cart->fees_api()->set_fees( $fees );

    return $order_id;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*